# MISRA C++ 2008 Rule 7–3–1 and Forward Declaration

Tags: c++, misra

Let's say I wanted to forward declare `CLibraryStruct` in my `MyClass.hpp`

```
class CLibraryStruct;

class MyClass {
    private:
    CLibraryStruct *cLibStr;
};
```

At the same time I also wanted to be compliant with `MISRA C++ 2008 Rule 7–3–1`:

> The global namespace shall only contain *main*, namespace declarations and *extern "C"* declarations.

I obviously can't use anonymous namespaces here, but I think I could try this:

```
class MyClass {
    private:
    class CLibraryStruct *cLibStr;
};
```

Or this:

```
#include "CLibrary.h"

class MyClass {
    private:
    CLibraryStruct *cLibStr;
};
```

Would you be so kind as to help me out and explain to me which would be a better choice (or suggest an alternative)?

Comment: `namespace my_ns { class CLibraryStruct; }` ?

Comment: @Frank
Wouldn't `CLibraryStruct` become `my_ns::CLibraryStruct` in this case while it would remain 'namespace-less' in `CLibrary.h`?

Comment: In that case just including `Clibrary.h`  would break compliance, and you have bigger problems to deal with,

Comment: Thank you, @Frank!